# Unity Animations C#

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, reference

I am making abilities for a game and I need to add animations (which I know how to do). My problem is I need a way to make a reference to animations without assigning a particular animation. I have a base class along with base logic for an ability (which is where I need a general reference because an ability does need an animation) and then when I want to make an ability I make a new class that inherits the base and then create the ability that way (which is where I would assign an animation).

```
//Default logic for abilities
public virtual void abilityEffects(hero caster, hero target){
    this.caster = caster;
    this.target = target;
    float DMG = damage * this.caster.heroAttPow;

    //Ability should not be on cooldown the first time it is used
    if (firstUse == true)
    {

        //sets the total damage to take into account the ability damage plus the hero power
        //need general reference to animation here
        //when animation is over, deal damage
        this.target.HP -= DMG;
        firstUse = false;
        //cooldown begins
        SpellStart = Time.time;
    }

    if(firstUse == false)
    {
        if (Time.time > SpellStart + SpellCooldown)
        {
            //sets the total damage to take into account the ability damage plus the hero power
            //need general reference to animation here
            //when animation is over, deal damage
            this.target.HP -= DMG;
            //cooldown begins
            SpellStart = Time.time;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using Mecanim to the animations?

Comment: If you know how to animate, it's time to learn to use Mecanim parameters and events.

Comment: @SergioOrmeño I use Blender for animations, then export to unity as a .fbx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an `Animator Component` controls all your object animations and states and if it is attached to your `gameobject` you can get a reference to it like this

```
public class player: MonoBehaviour { 
    public Animator anim;    
    public void Start() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
}
```

your class can also be `abstract` if you want to you just should call the start of the base class in the child class to get the reference to the `animator component`

```
public abstract class player: MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator anim;    
    public void Start() {     
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
}
public class PlayerChild: player{   
    void Start() {
        base.Start();        
    } 
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will give it a try. Thank you!